# How to run "npm run android" from java commande line linux

Tags: java, shell, command-line, react-native

I want to run :

```
export JAVA_HOME=/home/sofiane/install/jdk1.8.0_121/
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/sofiane/Android/Sdk/
npm run android
```

from a program java using commande line.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java class

```
public static void executeCommands() throws IOException {


            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("bash", "./shell.sh");
            pb.inheritIO();
            Process process = pb.start();

                try {
                    process.waitFor();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

    }
```

shell.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
export JAVA_HOME=/home/sofiane/install/jdk1.8.0_121/
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/sofiane/Android/Sdk/
cd /home/sofiane/work/MyAcceleo/fichier/pfe
npm run android
```

Result :
[image]